# How do I create a global document object usable in the main App struct?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am developing a simple SwiftUI macOS document app. In the main App struct I want to add menu items that modify the document object. In the Xcode app template for document based apps the main App struct looks similar to this if I add a menu item:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct GlobalDocApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        DocumentGroup(newDocument: GlobalDocDocument()) { file in
            ContentView(document: file.$document)
        }
        .commands {
            CommandMenu("Custom Menu") {
                Button("Modify it") {
                    //modify document properties...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I create the document object so that it is accessible from this struct as well as from the other view structs? Can the document object be used as an @EnvironmentObject throughout the app?

I tried declaring the document object as a @StateObject in the App struct but it needs to be observable and my GlobalDocDocument is a struct that is declared like this:

```swift
struct GlobalDocDocument: FileDocument
```

Comment: This might help: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@StateObject works only with classes. The only way you can use @StateObject with your document type is to make the document type a class. But there isn't much documentation on using classes for SwiftUI documents.

Add a @Binding variable in any SwiftUI view that needs to access the document, where the document type is a struct.

```
@Binding var document: GlobalDocDocument
```

You shouldn't have to create a binding in the app struct.

Use focused values and focused bindings to access the document in a SwiftUI menu. The following article explains how to access the document in a SwiftUI menu:

[Accessing the Document in a SwiftUI Menu](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/accessing-the-document-in-a-swiftui-menu/)